# Trying to write completion, then cd

Tags: fish

This seems so basic to me, but I've been unable to figure it out. So I wrote a completion that auto completes my code directories like the following:

```
complete --command dev --exclusive --arguments '(__fish_complete_directories (~/Code/))'
```

Now I'm trying to write a function that cd's into the chosen directory from the dev completion above.

This doesn't work but I hope you get what I'm trying to do:

```
function c
  cd dev
end
```

So when typing c, I want to get all my directories in the ~/Code/ directory as tab completion options, then when I select one, I want my current path to be taken to the chosen directory.

Btw - fish needs more docs :)

Comment: Using the `CDPATH` variable would be easier: `set -U CDPATH . ~/Code` -- http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#cd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're trying to do two things:

1. Create a function `c` that cd's to its argument
2. Make tab-completing `c` show paths in ~/Code

This is straightforward:

```
function c
    cd $argv
end

complete --command c --exclusive --arguments '(__fish_complete_directories ~/Code/)'
```

I'm not sure what `dev` is meant to be, but to be clear, the `--command` option to `complete` adds completions to an existing command. It does not define a new command.

Regarding documentation, there's lots at http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html. If there's areas you think need more coverage please open an issue at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess for some reason I wasn't clear that the complete functions add to an existing command. Must have missed that part.

Comment: I will add that adding the (~/Code/) hides the full path to the tab-completing. So my complete was as follows:
`complete --command c --exclusive --arguments '(__fish_complete_directories (~/Code/))'`